# Баг или очередная задокументированная фича?

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Думаю, комментарии излишни:

```
$a = (0.1 + 0.7) * 10;
$b = (0.01 + 0.07) * 100;

print  ($a); //8
print  (int)($a); //7
print "\n";
print ($b); // 8
print  (int)($b); //8
```

Comment: (facepalm) все же прокомментируй...

Answer (score 4):

Взято [отсюда](http://php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?float#erc)

> Точность числа с плавающей точкой
>
> Довольно часто простые десятичные дроби вроде 0.1 или 0.7 не могут быть преобразованы в свои внутренние двоичные аналоги без небольшой потери точности. Это может привести к неожиданным результатам: например, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) скорее всего возвратит 7 вместо ожидаемой 8 как результат внутреннего представления числа, являющегося в действительности чем-то вроде 7.9999999999....
>
> Это связано с невозможностью точно выразить некоторые дроби в десятичной системе счисления конечным числом цифр. Например, 1/3 в десятичной форме принимает вид 0.3333333. ...
>
> Так что никогда не доверяйте точности последних цифр в результатах с числами с плавающей точкой и никогда не проверяйте их на равенство. Если вам действительно необходима высокая точность, вам следует использовать математические функции произвольной точности или gmp-функции.

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем сакральный смысл приводить ссылку на какой-то левый клон, а не на официальную документацию?

[Числа с плавающей точкой](http://php.net/types.float)

[Преобразование в целое](http://php.net/types.integer#language.types.integer.casting)

Comment: Ну если автор вопроса сам сразу не пошёл в первоисточники, то может ему больше понравиться клоны?  :-)

P.S. Гугл посчитал этого клона более релевантным, или Вы думаете что я все эти ссылки в голове держу?

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет?

```
$c = (0.001 + 0.007) * 1000;
$d = (0.0001 + 0.0007) * 10000;
$e = -1*(0.1+0.7)*10
$f = -1*(0.01 + 0.07) * 100;
$g = -1*(0.001 + 0.007) * 1000;
$h = -1*(0.0001 + 0.0007) * 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй BCMath